# How to invoke $.modal.close() in scala.js

Tags: jquery, scala.js

I am using this [jQuery modal library](http://jquerymodal.com/) for modal dialogs. Using Scala.js, how do I invoke the same Javascript [`$.modal.close()`](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#closing) to close the modal dialog in Scala? Thanks

#### Update #1

Using https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade together with  https://github.com/jducoeur/jsext I have created these boilerplates to configure the modal dialog,

```
@js.native
trait JQueryModal extends JQuery {
 def modal(params: JQueryModalOptions): Nothing = js.native
}

@js.native
trait JQueryModalOptions extends js.Object
object JQueryModalOptions extends JQueryModalOptionsBuilder(noOpts)
class JQueryModalOptionsBuilder(val dict: OptMap) extends JSOptionBuilder[JQueryModalOptions, JQueryModalOptionsBuilder](new JQueryModalOptionsBuilder(_)) {
```

Comment: Do you use a facade library for jQuery? If yes, which one? Same questions about jQuery modal specifically. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Please refer to update #1. So far, I have created boilerplates to configure the modal dialog i.e. ```@js.native

trait JQueryModalOptions extends js.Object
object JQueryModalOptions extends JQueryModalOptionsBuilder(noOpts)
``` and ```@js.native
trait JQueryModal extends JQuery {
  def modal(params: JQueryModalOptions): Nothing = js.native
```. Next, I am stuck with ```$.modal.close()```

Comment: Looks like you got to a good solution.  My only additional comment would be that, in current versions of Scala.js, my jsext library is no longer terribly necessary -- it still works, but is mildly deprecated.  For the more current approach, see [this page](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/sjs-defined-js-classes.html), especially the sections "Anonymous classes" and "Configuration objects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the expected call site, `$.modal.close()`, we can see that `modal` is a property of the "static" parts of `$`, so you should pimp `JQueryStatic` instead of `JQuery`. `JQueryStatic` is the type of `$`, whereas `JQuery` is the type of things returned by `$(...)`.

Moreover, the `modal` field can be used with nested methods (as in `close()`) or as a function call itself (as in `$.modal(...)`). Therefore, it is best to model it as a trait with, among others, an `apply` method.

```scala
@js.native
trait JQueryModalStatic extends js.Object {
  def apply(params: JQueryModalOptions): Unit = js.native

  def close(): Unit = js.native
}

implicit class JQueryStaticToModalStatic(private val jQuery: JQueryStatic.type)
    extends AnyVal {

  @inline def modal: JQueryModalStatic =
    jQuery.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].modal.asInstanceOf[JQueryModalStatic]
}
```

When the implicit class is in scope (it has been imported), this allows to call both `$.modal(...)` (provided by the `apply` method definition) and `$.modal.close()`.

Comment: It works great. However, I could not get it to work without adding  `implicit def jq2JQueryModal(jq: JQuery): JQueryModal = jq.asInstanceOf[JQueryModal]` and `@js.native
trait JQueryModal extends JQuery {
  def modal(params: JQueryModalOptions): Unit = js.native
}` as I have `$("#foo").modal(defaultModalOptions)` in my code. If I understand your explanation correctly I have to implement for `JQuery` & `JQueryStatic`.

Comment: Yes, if `$("#foo").modal(...)` is a valid call, then you also need to pimp `def modal(...)` on `JQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

In my example I can show you how to do this with Semantic-UI modal.

I use this JQuery facade: `"be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.1"`

Then I use 'monkey patching':

```
object SemanticUI {

  // Monkey patching JQuery
  @js.native
  trait SemanticJQuery extends JQuery {
    def modal(params: js.Any*): SemanticJQuery = js.native
  }

  // Monkey patching JQuery with implicit conversion
  implicit def jq2semantic(jq: JQuery): SemanticJQuery = jq.asInstanceOf[SemanticJQuery]
}
```

In the code you can use this like:

```
import org.scalajs.jquery.jQuery
import SemanticUI.jq2semantic

<button class="ui basic icon button"
              onclick={_: Event =>
                setTimeout(200) {
                  jQuery(".ui.modal").modal("show")
                }
              }>open dialog</button>
```

Comment: I believe your suggestion works for bootstrap modal because the way it is invoked. For the modal library I'm using, "close" is a function. I'm thinking of using indirect  invocation ie `obj[x]`